# Banner start before modal shows up

Tags: html, modal-dialog, banner

I'm trying to show some banners with a bootstrap modal, but when the paga loads actually the banners start to run and when I open the modal i cant see the banner works.

This is an example of one of my modals:

```
<!--Delta banner-->
           <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
              <h3 class="feature-title">Delta</h3>
              <img src="images/delta_300x250.jpg" alt="">
              <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-outline-secondary btn-sm popOpen" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delta">View</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div onclick="javascript:window.location.reload()" class="modal fade" id="delta" role="dialog">
                 <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                       <div class="modal-header">
                          <h4 class="modal-title">Delta</h4>
                       </div>
                       <div class="modal-body">
                          <iframe src="banners/300x250_militaryp_092718/index.html" width="305px" height="255px" style="overflow: hidden; border: none;"></iframe>
                       </div>
                       <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" onclick="javascript:window.opener.location.reload()" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <!--Delta2 banner-->
```

Comment: make sure your file path is right?

Comment: Yes it's rigth, the problem is that the banner is loading when I load the page, so when I opens the modal the Banner has actually started